# Upgrading VM to Windows 10, install fails with Error 0xc1900101 0x20017 Error in phase safe_os

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 7 Guest (using VMWare Workstation 9).  When I attempt to upgrade to Windows 10, it gives me 2 options - troubleshoot, or power off.  After rebooting, it reverts to Windows 7, and gives me the above error message.

None of the troubleshooting options do anything effectively.

How do I get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Windows 10 does not like SCSI drives.  The VMWare VDisk was defaulted to SCSI when the VM was created.  All that was necessary, was to change the disk to an IDE interface, and retry the upgrade.  To do this, the steps are as follows:

1. Power down the VM.
2. Delete any snapshots.
3. Edit the VM Settings, and Remove the hard disk.
4. Edit the VMDK hard disk definition file with a text editor.
5. Edit or add the line ddb.adapterType = "ide"
6. In VMWare, add the disk back, using Existing Disk option.
7. Boot the VM, and continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, changing the disk type to IDE worked and allowed the Windows 10 upgrade to complete. My environment is ESX 5.5 U3.

To do this I also used a couple of tips from here:
http://www.ajpdsoft.com/modules.php?traducir=es-en&name=News&file=article&sid=645
This included the use of ssh to access the ESX datastore, also the use of Putty. I then used the vi line editor to alter my 35GB .VMDK file.

Thanks for the key part of the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Some blogs say, that for later updates some computers need a bios update.

So in the case examined here, the solution was to upgrade the virtual hardware version.
(I don't know how to do it in VMWare Workstation, but for vsphere the steps where as following.)

In vsphere Client:

1. don't know if required, but: uninstall vmware tools from windows host
2. shutdown the VM (and backup/clone)
3. then rightlick on the VM and select "Upgrade of virtual hardware" (or something like this)
4. start the VM and start the upgrade

(In this case we updated from hardware version 9 to 11 in vcenter/vsphere 6)

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many possible solutions only to find that it worked after installing all optional updates and not selecting to download the latest updates during installation. I tried this on both KVM vm as well as a gen 2 hyper-v conversion of the machine with an iscsi drive